# Duality Theorem. An example where the dual is feasible but the primal is not

Tags: examples-counterexamples, linear-programming, matlab

Can anyone provide an example where dual is feasible but the primal is not?  This is a linear programming question.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What do you allow as "dual"? The dual category of affine schemes, for example? What do mean by "feasable"?

Comment: This is in the realm of linear programme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primal:
$$\min_x \{0 : 0x \geq 1, x \geq 0\}$$
Dual:
$$\max_y \{ y : 0y \leq 0, y \geq 0\}.$$